# Увеличение номера build при разработке в Idea.

Tags: android, java, intellij-idea, build

Добрый вечер. 
Приложения пишутся под андройд.
В эклипсе я пробовал вставить скрипт на C#, который открывал файл манифеста и переписывал строку. Он вроде не работал, но скорее всего по причине не правильного парсинга.

Теперь я работаю в IDEA. Не могли бы подсказать, как там запускать скрипт до запуска программы, и может есть какие-нибудь готовые наработки?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у Вас последняя версия idea, то там используется gradle. А на нем можно сделать все что угодно - это полноценный язык. Более того, параметры манифеста уже [распарсены](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manifest-entries).

Если же используете старую версию idea (12), то там придется работать с ant. С ним также и эклипс работает, поэтому возможно, что Ваши наработки заработают. Почитать об этом можно [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107652/). Но использовать c# в андроид проектах для таких целей как то не по феншую.

Comment: @Kovadim , вот он повод обновить idea. 
Надеюсь при установки, он не собьет все мои настройки. 
Сейчас поставлю и отпишусь. 
Спасибо.

Comment: @KoVadim , а не подскажите, где в 12ой idea запускать проги перед запуском. Не могу понять. 
Добавляется где поле Before Launch: make ->> Run external tool ? 
Какие там важные поля потом?

Comment: Вы не путаете понятия "перед запуском" и "перед началом компиляции"?

найдите в своем проекте файл `build.xml`, это файл, который используется `ant` для построения проекта. В нам можно дописать различные правила для обработки. [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426750/how-to-automatically-modify-versionname-in-manifest-during-build) интересный, как по мне пост на SO.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за помощь, но я уже ночью сделал с тем же C# скриптом. Все работает.